# .NET Core app remote deployment to Windows IoT Core on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10, azure-iot-hub-device-management

With an UWP app I can deploy the appx package to a Raspberry Pi in multiple ways.

From [Update apps on your Windows 10 IoT Core devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps) (12/07/2017):

- Using Microsoft Store
- Using Device Update Center
- Using Azure IoT Device Management
- Using OMA-DM e.g SCCM

Is it possible to package a .NET Core app and use these channels to update it remotely (preferably via IoT Hub Device Management)?

Example scenarios are:

- Deployment of a new app to existing devices in the field
- Updating the version of the app already installed in the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some limitation when using Azure IoT Device Management:

- Note: Installing a new application from the store is not supported.
- Note: Updating applications other than the DM application from the store is not supported.

And also, you need create appx package for the app.

So, I am afraid the answer is NO.

Ref: 
[Application Management of Azure IoT Device Management client](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-core-azure-dm-client/blob/master/docs/application-management.md)